# R error in write.table >> Error in sc[[length(sc) - 7L]][[1L]] == "example"

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` object named `dat` where if I try `write.table(dat,'test.txt')`, I get this bizarre error:

```
'Error in sc[[length(sc) - 7L]][[1L]] == "example": comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types'
```

Following the stack trace takes me to cedta.R

cedta.R is way over my head. What is going on here and how do I address this issue?

In context, I read some data from a text file with `fread()`, then I select some rows from the table using a conditional, then I want to write the filtered table to a new text file. Pretty simple, I'm very confused what's wrong here.

```
dat <- fread(ptx, skip = 10, header = FALSE)
names(dat) <- c("X", "Y", "Z", "Intensity", "R", "G", "B")
ptx_header = readLines(ptx,n=2)
ncols = as.integer(ptx_header[1])
nrows = as.integer(ptx_header[2])

if (reducePtx==T){
  # Remove every other point from PTX file
  npoints = dim(dat)[1]
  cols = 0:(npoints-1) %/% ncols
  rows = rep.int(0:(nrows-1),ncols)
  dat1 = dat[cols%%2==0 & rows%%2==0,]
  remove(cols)
  remove(rows)

  # Write output ptx file
  ptx_out = paste0('reduced_',ptx)
  write.table(dat1,ptx_out,append = T,sep=' ',quote=F,row.names = F,col.names = F)}
```

Comment: Interesting error, and it doesn't immediately seem possible to tell with your example, as it is not reproducible (we do not have your data). Any reason in particular that you are using `write.table` over `fwrite`(the counterpart to `fread`)? Perhaps you have overwritten the value of `T` or `F`at some point, and this might cause interesting things to happen. `rm(T, F)` would take care of that.

Comment: You need to provide session info, most important is data.table version

Comment: This line of code has changed and does not use == comparison anymore in 1.14.2. Try upgrading dt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, and the best I could come up with was converting the object to a data.frame before writing it.  In other words, instead of `write.table(dat,'test.txt')` try `write.table(as.data.frame(dat),'test.txt')`.  Not very satisfying, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the confusing error readout, it seems to be a data type issue between data.frames and data.tables. Using fwrite from the data.table package works fine or it sounds like casting to a data.frame works fine.